# Is it possible to break a string and store it a matrix?

Tags: python

Suppose i have a string `ci='SKDKFJKFLKG'` and I want to store it in a matrix.I am using the following code to store it in a matrix:

```
def chunks(l, n):

    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]
pprint.pprint(list(chunks(ci, 1)))
```

Output:

```
['S', 'K', 'D', 'K', 'F', 'J', 'K', 'F', 'L', 'K', 'G']
```

What should i do if i want only 4 characters in each row of the matrix?

Comment: That’s a 4x3 matrix… and where did the space go?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What did you try?

Comment: Note that a string is just a list of characters, so the linked question will help you solve this for strings too.

Comment: I have removed the spaces.@ivan_pozdeev I am not sure how to do it.I am taking a look at the link that you provided.

Comment: The question is still a duplicate. Read the linked solution carefully to understand what you should pass to `chunks`.